# Asking for 'Pairing Request' in android 2.1 when connecting to Bluetooth Socket SPP on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connected to Bluetooth with Socket SPP using my Samsung Galaxy Tablet using UUID of `"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`, but that doesn't not work for me.

And I have tried using the following:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
sock.connect();
```

This is working fine, but everytime I try to connect, it's asking for pairing request PIN, failing of that is leading to failure of bluetooth connection.

How can I set/save the pair information so that it should not prompt pairing request every time I connect.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with my Motorola DROID v1 running Android 2.2.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839795/prompted-for-bluetooth-pin-when-connecting-to-already-paired-device-on-android

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem as well. This is probably Android ICS issue. As a workaround you can use Insecure Socket

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
sock.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Bluetooth settings on the Android settings menu and permanently pair the device! Have you tried this before?